# Reposition the center of the map when the location changes?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm using the `react-google-maps` library. I'm trying to recenter my map (zoom where the marker is) every time my location changes, but I'm getting a bit lost on how to implement the whole thing. I can see the marker being updated, but the map stays on its `defaultCenter` position.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
} from 'react-google-maps';

import environment from '../../config/environment';

class Map extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    defaultZoom: PropTypes.number,
    center: PropTypes.shape({
      lat: PropTypes.number,
      lng: PropTypes.number
    }),
    location: PropTypes.shape({
      lat: PropTypes.number,
      lng: PropTypes.number
    }),
    onPositionChanged: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    defaultZoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 60.1699,
      lng: 24.9384
    },
    location: {},
    onPositionChanged: () => {}
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapRef = React.createRef((ref) => {
      this.mapRef = ref;
    });
  }

  componenDidUpdate() {
    console.log(`I'm about to update with props: ${JSON.strongify(prevProps, undefined, 2)}`);
  }

  onPositionChanged = (location) => {
    console.log(`This the new location onPositionChange:${JSON.stringify(location, undefined, 2)}`);
    const newLocation = new window.google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
    // [NOTE]: try using the panTo() from googleMaps to recenter the map ? but don't know how to call it.

    return (
      <Marker
        position={newLocation}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {
      center,
      defaultZoom,
      location,
      onPositionChanged
    } = this.props;

    return (

      <GoogleMap
        className="google-map"
        onClick={onPositionChanged(location)}
        defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
        defaultCenter={center}
        ref={this.mapRef}
      >

        {/* <Marker
          position={location}
        /> */}

        { this.onPositionChanged(location) }
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}

const SchedulerGoogleMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
const SchedulerMap = props => (
  <SchedulerGoogleMap
    googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${
      environment.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
    }&v=3`}
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '20vh' }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: '20vh', width: '100%' }} />}
    {...props}
  />
);


export { Map, SchedulerMap, SchedulerGoogleMap };
```

Comment: Share codesandbox and we can use fitBounds

Answer (score 22):

Simply pass the `center` prop to your `GoogleMap` component instead of the `defaultCenter` prop. The `center` prop is mutable whereas `defaultZoom is not`.

Comment: Code example: ```<GoogleMap zoom={zoom}  center={center}>```

Comment: Thanks! I think you meant `defaultCenter` not `defaultZoom`.

Comment: defualt center will not be change if you even pass the updated state it will remain same, if you to recenter the map according to the searched location then use another prop center and pass updated state to that prop

Answer (score 3):

This is what it seemed to work for me, just in case any other person runs into the same problem.

```
... ommited_code

class Map extends Component {

... ommited_code

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location !== this.props.location) {
      this.mapRef.panTo(
        new window.google.maps.LatLng(this.props.location.lat, this.props.location.lng)
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      center,
      defaultZoom,
      location
    } = this.props;

    return (

      <GoogleMap
        className="google-map"
        defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
        defaultCenter={center}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.mapRef = ref;
        }}
      >
        <Marker position={new window.google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng)} />
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}

...ommited_code
```

Comment: No this is not right, instead od this you just need to pass center prop with updated coordinates

Answer (score 0):

`panTo()` is a method of the google.maps.Map class. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panTo)

It seems to be the function you are looking for, so you need to call it on your google map by referencing the className you set for your map, then give the `panTo` method the `LatLang` object you created:

`window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("google-map")).panTo(newLocation);`

Comment: just tried it, but it gives me a `cannot find defaultView` error when I try to set it on `onPositionChanged` method

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, add a Key property to the Map and update the key with each center change. That should do it

```
const [mapKey, setMapKey] = useState(0);

  const handleMapLoad = (map) => {
    // Now you can use the map instance here
    console.log("Map instance:", map);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (centerCords) {
      setMapCenter({ lat: centerCords.lat, lng: centerCords.lng });
      // Update the key to force re-render when the center changes
      setMapKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
    }
  }, [centerCords]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
      <APIProvider apiKey={'Your API key here'}>
        <Map
          id={"mymap"}
          key={mapKey} // Add a key to force re-render
          zoom={10}
          center={mapCenter}
          onLoad={handleMapLoad}
        >
       </Map>
      </APIProvider>
    </div>
```